# Socket not listed in lsof but is listed in netstat

Tags: tcp, netstat, lsof

When I do "lsof -nl | egrep "TCP|UDP" " in order to see socket states, I notice that the sockets that I expected to be listed are not at all, but when I do a "netstat --tcp", they are listed, but are in a CLOSE_WAIT state.

What I know so far is that the CLOSE_WAIT state signifies that my application has a responsibility now to explicitly close this socket (but there is a bug that I'm trying to track down, which keeps this socket in a CLOSE_WAIT state). I thought that if a socket exists, then it must have an open file descriptor associated with it, so I expected to see it on the output of lsof. Why is it that I couldn't see it there?

Thanks,
Sandra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have enough permissions? (And I think this belongs to superuser)